# i can boot from cd/dvd but not read it in windows

Tags: compact-disc, cd

i can boot ok from cd or dvd. In windows 7, I can't read a disk. I can write to it but not read. When I click "open" it ask me to put a disk in and opens the tray. It won't play music or video. Device manager says that the drive functions with no problem. Listed in bios but not recognized. Microsoft fixer says there is no problem. No driver problems, no registry filters to get rid of, substituting the drive and cable gives the same error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of the contents on the disc? What are the file extensions? Can you provide us a link to what is on the disc?

Comment: I installed windows 7 today on an old disk I had lying around. The drive works there like it should. As to your question, it opens absolutely nothing. It does not matter what is on the disk, it will not show it. Obviously the problem is with windows

Answer (score -1):

Go to the manufacturer's website and check for drivers for your system.  If you find that the website says Windows drivers are preferred to use, remove the device from Device Manager and refresh to discover new devices.  When the drivers are reinstalled and still does not function, go get a new DVD player. I saw a few for around $20 on Amazon.